# Мне нужно в Telegram сделать бота который постил бы футбольные голы в лайв режиме

Tags: php, python, api

Мне нужно в Telegram сделать бота который постил бы футбольные голы в лайв режиме. Как это можно реализовать и на каких ЯП писать?

Comment: Мне кажется, Вам - [сюда](https://www.google.com/search?q=telegram+bot+api+libraries)

Answer (score 2):

Да, это возможно, но боту понадобится база данных или любое другое место, откуда брать информацию про голы. ЯП не важен, ибо насколько мне известно, боты в Телеграме работают на API запросах, а значит не привязаны к какой-то библиотеке.

Изменено: Насколько я понял, у Telegram есть в том числе и библиотеки для взаимодействия с ботом. Выбор языков очень велик, так что сложностей возникнуть не должно ни при каком из случаев (API либо API Library). Ссылка на список авторизованных библиотек для ботов от Telegram отправлен в комментарий к вопросу одним из пользователей. Удачи :).

Comment: Могу ли я как то взять базу с этого сайта Myscore.ru ???

Comment: Если Вы не являетесь авторизированным работником данного сервиса, то, скорее всего, нет. Но Вы можете попробовать поискать секций для разработчиков и найти нужные инструменты, либо же попоробовать написать в поддержку. Вполне возможно, что такие  услуги предоставляются на платной основе (Если предоставляются). На крайний случай можно парсить HTML, либо получить ссылку на которую делаются запросы через инструменты браузера и попробовать получить нужную информацию оттуда.